# Power Automate - Can't navigate to folder or obtain folder id

Tags: power-automate

this is a general question about Power Automate and OneDrive that I've seen no solution to.
I'm trying to create a flow "Copy files from a folder in OneDrive (Business) to an FTP server".  The trigger is "When a filed is created" in a OneDrive directory.    When I attempt to navigate to the folder I just see ROOT, then "No Items".

I also can't figure out how to obtain the unique identifier of the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was attempting to do this using OneDrive(Business) when I should have used Sharepoint based on my organization's license

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the ID of my folders with this short Instant flow.

[image: Instant Flow to get list of files in root OneDrive Directory]

It'll output a JSON response with the ID, Name, Path, etc for all your folders in the Root of OneDrive. There is also a "List files in folder" block that you can use to get subfolders of folders.

I was able to copy the ID string from the JSON response and paste it into the "When a file is create" OneDrive trigger and have it go off successfully.

Comment: The issue was I was attempting to do this using OneDrive(Business) when I should have used Sharepoint based on my organization's license.